# salesforce oauth authorization end point error

Tags: .net, salesforce, oauth-2.0, windows-phone-8

oauth authorizat​ion end point error(HELP​!)
I am trying to navigate to this end point but get an error:

> URL no longer exists.

[https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/autho​rize?response_type=code&client_id="my clientID"&re... ="my Uri"](https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/autho%E2%80%8Brize?response_type=code&client_id="my%20clientID"&re...%20="my%20Uri")

Has the authorisation end point for salesforce webserver agent flow changed ,or is there something else I am missing out.

Answer (score 0):

It's there.  You can plug the root URL (https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize) into a browser and see that it passes back an API response.  Are you sure that your URL is well-formed in your app?  Any unnecessary URL encoding going on?

Comment: Did that get you past your (immediate) issue, or are you still running into the same "no longer exists" error in your app?